# Method [validateRequire] does not exist

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am making a data validation, but it throws this error:

```
 exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Method [validateRequire] does not exist.' in G:\WEB\litraen\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php:3265
```

when performing the validation.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Requests;

class UserController extends Controller
{


    public function Register(Request $request){

       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required|max:25',
            'email' => 'require|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'require|min:6'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()){
             return response()->json([
                 'success' => false,
                 'errors' => $validator->errors()->toArray()
             ]);
        }
           return response()->json([
                'success' => true
              ]);
        }
    }
```

why shows  this error?
that could have wrong?

Thank you :)

Comment: Change `'name' => 'required|max:25',` to `'name' => 'require|max:25',`

Answer (score 46):

**SOLUTION:**

```
'name' => 'required|max:25',
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
'password' => 'required|min:6'
```

lacked the "d"

Comment: It was a typo for me as well, using a `.` as the separator of two of the rules instead of a `,`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just posting this maybe someone will got the same error. 
U should change `require` to `required`, as bellow:

```
 'name' => 'required|max:25',
 'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
 'password' => 'required|min:6'
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the validation "require", change to "required".
That should allow it to run.

Answer (score -1):

```
'name' => 'required|max:25',
'password' => 'required|min:6',
```

Comment: change spelling from require to required.